# Swap Widgets on Toggle switch press in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget, setstate

I'm trying to implement a widget swap for a ToggleSwitch in flutter. So far I have worked around to change the swap of widgets and toggleSwitch separately. I need to combine them so when I select a toggle switch it will show the widget it need to show and when the other toggle switch clicked the second widget come into view.
Even when I work that the widgets are swapping, the ToggleSwitch does not change it's state.
Please help me in improving this. Many Thanks in advance.

here is the build() code snippet I'm trying to work out.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final petHeader = Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'hero',
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 30.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey[300],
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage(
                      'assets/images/logo_small.png',
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Dog Name',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Age',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 12.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Daily Guide',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, color: Colors.black87),
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final macroCharts = Center(
      child: Text('macro chart here'),
    );

    final microCharts = Center(
      child: Text('micro chart here'),
    );

    Widget getMacroChart(){
      return Center(
            child: Text('macro chart here'),
          );
    }

    Widget getMicroChart(){
      return Center(
        child: Text('micro chart here'),
      );
    }

    Widget getCustomContainer() {
      switch (selectedWidget) {
        case widgetMarker.macro:
          return getMacroChart();
        case widgetMarker.micro:
          return getMicroChart();
      }
      return getMacroChart();
    }

    final userSaveBtn = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0, bottom: 4.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ToggleSwitch(
        cornerRadius: 4.0,
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        fontSize: 20.0,
        initialLabelIndex: 0,
        activeBgColor: Color(0xFF03B898),
        activeFgColor: Colors.white,
        inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey[300],
        inactiveFgColor: Colors.black54,
        labels: ['   Macro\nNutrients', '   Micro\nNutrients'],
        onToggle: (index) {
          print('switched to: $index');
          setState(() {
            _swapNutrients = !_swapNutrients;
          });
        },
      ),
    );

    var swapTile = new Container(
      child: _swapNutrients ? macroCharts : microCharts,
    );

    final body =
        Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Welcome Alucard',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.black87),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: userSaveBtn,
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 7,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: swapTile,//getCustomContainer(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

    final lorem = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit condimentum mauris id tempor. Praesent eu commodo lacus. Praesent eget mi sed libero eleifend tempor. Sed at fringilla ipsum. Duis malesuada feugiat urna vitae convallis. Aliquam eu libero arcu.',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );

    final mainBody = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 16.0,
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 12.0,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [0.5, 1.0],
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF03B898),
            Color(0xFF01816B),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // SizedBox(height: 32.0),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: petHeader,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 11,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: body,
            ),
          ),
          // lorem,
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: mainBody, //_isShowingDialog ? bodyWithDialog : bodyWithCharts
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you mean the Toggle switch activation is not changed?
If that, I am sorry that I misunderstood your issue.

I confirm that toggle switch activation's changing by click.

Because whenever build() is executed, toggle switch's 'initialLabelIndex' is 0, there is no activation changing.

Here is a change point.

```
initialLabelIndex: _swapNutrients ? 0 : 1,
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:toggle_switch/toggle_switch.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool _swapNutrients = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final petHeader = Container(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      color: Colors.white,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Hero(
              tag: 'hero',
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Container(),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'Dog Name',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'Age',
                    style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black87),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: 12.0,
              ),
              child: Text(
                'Daily Guide',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32.0, color: Colors.black87),
                textAlign: TextAlign.end,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );

    final macroCharts = Center(
      child: Text('macro chart here'),
    );

    final microCharts = Center(
      child: Text('micro chart here'),
    );

    Widget getMacroChart() {
      return Center(
        child: Text('macro chart here'),
      );
    }

    Widget getMicroChart() {
      return Center(
        child: Text('micro chart here'),
      );
    }

    final userSaveBtn = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0, bottom: 4.0),
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      // width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      child: ToggleSwitch(
        cornerRadius: 4.0,
        minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        minHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
        fontSize: 20.0,
        initialLabelIndex: _swapNutrients ? 0 : 1,
        activeBgColor: Color(0xFF03B898),
        activeFgColor: Colors.white,
        inactiveBgColor: Colors.grey[300],
        inactiveFgColor: Colors.black54,
        labels: ['   Macro\nNutrients', '   Micro\nNutrients'],
        onToggle: (index) {
          print('switched to: $index');
          print('switched to: $_swapNutrients');
          setState(() {
            _swapNutrients = !_swapNutrients;
          });
        },
      ),
    );

    var swapTile = new Container(
      child: _swapNutrients ? macroCharts : microCharts,
    );

    final body = Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: [
        Expanded(
          flex: 3,
          child: Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.transparent,
            child: Card(
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Welcome Alucard',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28.0, color: Colors.black87),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 6,
          child: Card(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 1,
                    child: userSaveBtn,
                  ),
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 7,
                    child: Container(
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      child: swapTile, //getCustomContainer(),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );

    final lorem = Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: Text(
        'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec hendrerit condimentum mauris id tempor. Praesent eu commodo lacus. Praesent eget mi sed libero eleifend tempor. Sed at fringilla ipsum. Duis malesuada feugiat urna vitae convallis. Aliquam eu libero arcu.',
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.white),
      ),
    );

    final mainBody = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 16.0,
      ),
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 12.0,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
          stops: [0.5, 1.0],
          colors: [
            Color(0xFF03B898),
            Color(0xFF01816B),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          // SizedBox(height: 32.0),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: petHeader,
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 11,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
              child: body,
            ),
          ),
          // lorem,
        ],
      ),
    );

    return Scaffold(
      body: mainBody, //_isShowingDialog ? bodyWithDialog : bodyWithCharts
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: even this changes the view of the widget , the toggle does not change it's state(plainly saying-> toggle switch does not show it changes to touch). I'm thinking to figure that out

Comment: I want to see your build() code. Because when 'setState' is called, build method will be executed.

Comment: I changed answer, please try testing this.

Comment: it changes the widget container under the toggle switch, but the toggle switch does not change its toggle(from micro to macro and vice versa). that's where I'm stuck with this. FYI I'm using a package called ToggleSwitch

Comment: I attached my test result screenshot. Isn't this what you want to do?

Comment: dang !!! ^_^ come to see that, it was way clearly obvious that there should be the place I need to attend to, thank you so much for the help KUKU. I appreciate it so much.